# How to update cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've been using an older version of cocos2d for iPhone for an existing project - never change a running system. Now I'd like to upgrade to a more recent version and don't know how I should proceed about this.

Just install a newer version? Will the install script overwrite all of the old files and take care of the old templates too? Or do I have to remove the old files manually - and if so, which files do I need to remove?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://learngamedev.screenstepslive.com/spaces/learn-cocos2d-public-content/manuals/cocos2d-general/lessons/14535-How-to-update-the-cocos2d-iphone-code-in-a-project-created-with-a-cocos2d-Project-Template-) is the answer.

Comment: Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com) includes a project upgrade tool. Migrating to Kobold2D is straightforward (http://www.kobold2d.com/x/zAMO). Anyway, I've since written a much more detailed tutorial if you want to stick with cocos2d: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/

Comment: The link in the answer is dead

Answer (score 1):

Don't know well cocos2D, but save your project and just try to replace the old library with the new one ;-) just don't forget to save you current project... in the case ;-)

If the library didn't change too much, it should work.

Good Luck